# Unable to render HAML in Codepen can't find error

Tags: ruby, haml

I'm working on the FreeCodeCamp Survey Form project.
I've ran into a problem that seems to be with indentation I'm not sure if this is a limitation with codepen or if It's just my own ignorance and bad code.

The issue starts at:

```
%div.field
  %label.label
  %ul.options
  - @item = ['Single Player', 'Multiplayer', 'Local Coop', 'MMO', 'MOBA', 'Casual', 'Other']
  - item.each_with_index do |item, i|
     %li.option
        %input.option-input{name: 'option', type: 'radio', value: i, id: "option-#{i}"}/
        %label.option-label{:for => "option-#{i}"}= item
```

[Pen](https://codepen.io/ChristianJJohnson/pen/zbjPRM?editors=1010)

Comment: Finally got an actual error: "CodePen removed the words below from your Haml because they could be used to do bad things. Please remove them and try again. 
->system" still just as lost to why.

Answer (score 0):

CodePen said on Twitter that they strip certain keywords from preprocessed code for security reasons. 2 years ago they said they had plans to make that error friendlier.

https://twitter.com/kosai106/status/762348280156151809